# ChromeDriver: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python

I am trying to run chromedriver in python. It gives me TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.

```
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver = "C:/Users/maddy.han/Downloads/chromedriver"
driver=webdriver.chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("http:google.com")
```

Can someone help me with the troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong name to create a driver. `webdriver.Chrome` is the class you need to create a Chrome driver. This class is an alias for `webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver`. Here `webdriver.chrome` is a python module, where the chrome webdriver and other related classes live. Notice that Python is case sensitive so `chrome` and `Chrome` stands for different things here. You may read [the document](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver) for more information.

Also, the format of URL is `protocol://web.site` so your last line should be `http://google.com` instead :).

Comment: Thank you so much for answering it. I made changes based on your suggest. Then I see a new error: WebDriverException: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home.

Comment: I suggest you make a little change  in your code: 


from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

Using this, you don't need to install chromedriver manually. This is downloaded automatically by the framework. 

More info here: https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/

Comment: @MaddyHan Is your driver path correct? Since your are on Windows maybe the correct path should be "C:/Users/maddy.han/Downloads/chromedriver.exe".

Comment: Yes. the path was not right. I just fixed it. It worked! Thank you both so much :)